# Partial string match translation table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Column A has a long string in it.  I need to find if any of the 50 words in column B (1 word per row) are in each row in column A.  After that, whichever word matched from column B I need the corresponding number in column C.

I've tried different VLookups, Match, and Index formulas with no luck.  If I need to clarify the problem please let me know.

Edit: Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: You should add some examples of the output you're looking for.

Comment: Just linked an example.

Comment: You can either use VBA or an Array formula. Have you tried any of those? And what if there are multiple match?

Comment: I was looking at array formula's, have never used them though, is there any good examples out there?

Also, there will not be multiple matches.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

Add this formula in `F2` and drag down:

`=LOOKUP(2^50,SEARCH($C$2:$C$5,A2),$D$2:$D$5)`

This is **not** an array formula.

Comment: +1 nice one. This makes me appreciate `LOOKUP` more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a custom formula.  Add this module to your excel file:

```vb
Public Function match_keyword(CellVar As Range)
'Insert a blank column
'add the excel function "=match_keyword(A1)"
'in it, you will see a number which represents the first matching keyword

If InStr(CellVar.Value, "blue") > 0 Then
    match_keyword = 1
ElseIf InStr(CellVar.Value, "green") > 0 Then
    match_keyword = 2
ElseIf InStr(CellVar.Value, "red") > 0 Then
    match_keyword = 3
Else
    'no match found
    match_keyword = 0
End If
End Function
```

Modify the code to include all your keywords, and their corresponding number.

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I was doing to start, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way than creating 50 if statements.

Comment: Maybe not an easier way, but a more elegant solution would be to use an array.  I posted an example as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same concept, but using an array...

```vb
Public Function match_keyword2(CellVar As Range)

'initialize at zero
match_keyword2 = 0

Dim keyword_ARRAY(1 To 3) As String
keyword_ARRAY(1) = "blue"
keyword_ARRAY(2) = "green"
keyword_ARRAY(3) = "red"

For i = LBound(keyword_ARRAY) To UBound(keyword_ARRAY)
    If InStr(CellVar.Value, keyword_ARRAY(i)) > 0 Then
        match_keyword2 = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

...then modify the code to include your list of keywords.

Comment: So the problem is my list of keywords will continuously grow and probably be over a few hundred

Comment: A macro won't help you unless it is given a list of keywords. However, once you find that the edits are unmanageable, you may want to consider reading the keywords from a separate tab in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula:

`=INDEX(D$2:D$5,IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(C$2:C$5,A2),0))>0,MATCH(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(C$2:C$5,A2),0)),IFERROR(SEARCH(C$2:C$5,A2),0),0),NA()))`

Entered in `F2` as Array Formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Result:**
[image]